# Make moveable image button static once moved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this code that allows me to move the image button around the screen. but i want to know how i would be able to move the image button to another position and once at the point it changes allows me to click the button but not movable. Yeah i would like the button to be moved the first time they move it and then the next time that they come back to the site the button is not movable.

```
  var x; 
    var y;
    var bool;
    bool =1;
    function move(event){
          x= event.clientx;
          y = event.clienty
          document.getElementByID('img_btn').style.top=y+'px';
          document.getElementByID('img_btn').style.left=y+'px';
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to button to be movable just once and then become static? Would be helpful if you provide the markup for the button itself so we can see what event is being handled. Best option is to simply remove the handler once move if that is the desired effect.

Comment: Yeah i would like the button to be moved the first time they move it and then the next time that they come back to the site the button is not movable.

Comment: A very far fetched idea is to use ajax to store the boolean value and fetch it again on `document.ready`. But as I said, this is really complex and may be too much for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to be static for the next visit then you should save the "moved" variable to either a cookie or serverside.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the boolean as a conditional statement for whether the button has already been moved. For instance:

```
var x; 
var y;
var moved;
moved = false;
function move(event){
      if(!moved){
          x = event.clientx;
          y = event.clienty
          document.getElementByID('img_btn').style.top=y+'px';
          document.getElementByID('img_btn').style.left=y+'px';

          moved = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: this wouldnt work because if the user was to come back to the page then it will be movable again and not static

Comment: Answered this before he said it should be static after returning to the page.. Store it in the session or something server side. All the code is reset every time you return to the page.